# Cron stopped in google cloud run

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, cron, google-cloud-run

I have created a cron with crond + Alpine in Google Cloud Run

All work, but after minutes the cron is stopped when container no receive any request across http.

But if you do not reload the web page after at least 30 minutes cron is stopped.

Any idea what is wrong?

This is my dockerfile.

```
FROM python:3.8-alpine

RUN apk --no-cache add musl-dev linux-headers g++
RUN apk add --no-cache build-base dcron tzdata
RUN apk add --no-cache libffi-dev

COPY cronjobs /var/spool/cron/crontabs/root

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY requirements.txt ./

ENV TZ="America/Montevideo"

RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt

COPY . .

ENV PORT 8080
ENV FLASK_APP app.py
ENV FLASK_RUN_HOST 0.0.0.0

RUN chmod a+x startup.sh
CMD ["./startup.sh"]
```

cronjob

```
*/15 * * * * cd /usr/src/app && python3 test.py >> cron.txt 2>&1
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nothing is wrong in respect to how Cloud Run is designed.

When there are no requests, the Cloud Run container is suspended. This means you cannot do background tasks. Cloud Run is an HTTP Request/Response system. When Cloud Run returns the HTTP response and there are no other requests being processed, your CPU is stopped.

> After startup, you should only expect to be able to do computation
> within the scope of a request: a container instance does not have any
> CPU allocated if it is not processing a request.

[Container runtime contract](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/reference/container-contract)